# Nested itemize but using the original bullet?

Tags: itemize

I have a nested itemize

```
\begin{itemize} 
         \item 
     \begin{itemize}  
         \item  
     \end{itemize} 
\end{itemize}
```

The problem is that the nested itemize has bullet "-" which looks like a minus sign...

Is it possible to somehow use the original bullet?

I found \cdot to be too small and \bullet to be too big.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

By use of the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{label=\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item some text
     \begin{itemize}
         \item some text
     \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. We need to preserve your brain somehow.